# String replace not working if the replacement string contains $

Tags: javascript

I'm having an issue that I am not able to understand. Here is an small example:

```
var Original="xxx?{AND tr.consumer = '$Msisdn$'}\nSomething\nSomething else",
    replacement="AND tr.consumer = '$Msisdn$'",
    replace="?{AND tr.consumer = '$Msisdn$'}"
```

Then if I execute `Original.replace(replace,replacement)` What I get is that the replacement sentence is not complete on the result. This is what i get:

```
"AND tr.consumer = '$Msisdn"
```

I can't understand the reasons.
Many thanks.

Comment: `$` is a special character in `RegExp`, you need to escape it

Comment: checkout the [example](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Switching_words_in_a_string) in the docs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `replace` function works with regular expressions, as well as normal strings.  Because of this, the replacement string can have special characters in too, `$` is one of these.  You [need to escape it](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Specifying_a_string_as_a_parameter):

```
var Original="xxx?{AND tr.consumer = '$Msisdn$'}\nSomething\nSomething else",
    replacement="AND tr.consumer = '$$Msisdn$$'",
    replace="?{AND tr.consumer = '$Msisdn$'}"
```

Comment: As I said in the comment of my own answer, many thanks fur such fast response. What if the replacement string was generated dinamycally? I mean, as a result of another regular expression (/\?\{[^}]*\}/) that includes it. Can I do replacement.replace("$","$$") without going into a loop?

Comment: You could do - at some point you'll get to a replacement string that's not auto generated - ie just `replacement.replace('$', '$$$$')` should do it.

Comment: Since the `$` character can appear many times, I have to use a regex. `replacement.replace(/\$/g,"$$$$")` did the trick. Many thanks, I was using just  a single `$$`, which had no effect.

Comment: Yeah that will end up replacing it with a single `$` - you need to use 4 which will reduce to 2

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I have checked the replace documentation, and what some people has pointed is correct. It's a special character, and should be escaped:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace

I first tried escaping it the how I "thought" it was correct, but I did ti wrong. I was doing `\$`
But the correct way is:

```
Pattern Inserts
$$  Inserts a "$".
```

If the replacement string is not manually generated, and contains `$` characters, you can just escape them with the following sentence `replacement.replace(/\$/g,"$$$$")`

Comment: Wow, many people have answered while I was writing my own response. Many thanks to all of you. I'm amazed how fast the answers were.

Comment: Yeah - SO is _very_ active, especially in tags like javascript.  Always worth waiting around for a few minutes after asking a question to see if people are asking for clarifications etc.